# loess on grouped data in plotly does not work properly

Tags: r, plotly

I want to create a plot with loess on grouped data in plotly. It does not work properly, because it produces only one line. It seems it's a bug.

```
df <- data.frame(
         id  = rep(1:1000, 3),
         value = c(rnorm(1000,mean = 2), 
                   rnorm(1000,mean = 4), 
                   rnorm(1000,mean = 6)),
         var = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 1000))

# ggplot2 - it works as it should be
ggplot(df, aes(id, value, color  = var)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess")

# plotly - it doesn't work properly
df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~id) %>%
  add_markers( y = ~value, color = ~var) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~fitted(loess(value ~ id)), color = ~var)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior since you are not fitting loess by group in the `add_lines` call.

Here is an approach in which you first calculate the fit by group and then plot

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

df %>% 
  group_by(var) %>%
  mutate(fit = fitted(loess(value ~ id))) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~id) %>%
  add_markers( y = ~value, color = ~var, alpha = 0.5) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~fit, color = ~var)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you load `tidyverse` for this? It works for me without it.

Comment: @Frans Rodenburg I load `tidyverse` every time I start R, it has become a habit of mine. In this example I use `%>%`, `group_by` and `mutate` which are part of `dplyr` and `dplyr` is part of `tidyverse`.